# How to call a parent component function via a child component and props in Reac.js?

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I want to change the parent component state with the child component.

I create a function in the parent component and pass it to the child component via props.

Products component code :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Product from './product';

class Products extends Component {
    state = {
        products: [
            { id: 1, count: 2, productName: 'laptp' },
            { id: 2, count: 1, productName: 'phone' },
            { id: 3, count: 4, productName: 'airpods' }
        ]
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <>
                {this.state.products.map((p, index) => (
                    <Product onClick={this.handleDelete} id={p.id} key={index} productName={p.productName} count={p.count} >
                        Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                    </Product>
                ))}
            </>
        );
    }

    handleDelete = (productId) => {
        console.log(productId);
    }

}

export default Products;
```

Product component code :

```
import { Component } from "react";


class Product extends Component {
  state = {
    count: this.props.count,
    productName: this.props.productName
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <span className="m-2 text-info"> {this.props.productName}</span>
        <span className="m-2 badge bg-primary">{this.format(this.count)}</span>
        <button onClick={this.handleIncrement} className="m-2 btn btn-sm btn-success">+</button>
        <button onClick={this.handleDecrement} className="m-2 btn btn-sm btn-warning">-</button>
        <button onDelete={this.handleDelete()} className="m-2 btn btn-sm btn-danger">delete</button>
        <p>{this.props.children}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
  handleIncrement = () => {
    const { count } = this.state;
    this.setState({ count: count + 1 });
  }
  handleDecrement = () => {
    const { count } = this.state;
    this.setState({ count: count - 1 });
  }
  handleDelete = () => {
    this.props.handleDelete(this.props.id)
  }
  format() {
    if (this.state.count === 0) {
      return "zero";
    } else {
      return this.state.count;
    }
  }
}
export default Product;
```

index.js code :

```
import Products from "./components/products";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(<Products />);
```

When I start the project get the error :

What I problem? How can I fix it?

```
this.props.handleDelete is not a function
TypeError: this.props.handleDelete is not a function
    at Product.handleDelete (http://localhost:3000/main.a60ab9ca1348fe27abe1.hot-update.js:47:18)
    at Product.render (http://localhost:3000/main.a60ab9ca1348fe27abe1.hot-update.js:83:23)
    at finishClassComponent (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:23142:35)
    at updateClassComponent (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:23099:28)
    at beginWork (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:24725:20)
    at beginWork$1 (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:29665:18)
    at performUnitOfWork (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:28935:16)
    at workLoopSync (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:28858:9)
    at renderRootSync (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:28831:11)
    at recoverFromConcurrentError (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:28323:24)
```

Comment: The prop you're passing to `Product` is `onClick`, not `handleDelete`

Comment: @NickParsons  I updated it but does not solve it.